# refresh an int64edit and get selected element

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, axapta, ax, dynamics-ax-2012

Refresh an int64edit and get selected element.

I have an int64edit, when I select a value I would like to get back this value.

Which method should I use or override ? I tried to override the method " validate " In which I used ValueStr to get the value but it doesn't work as I hoped. some suggestions ?

Comment: Could you elaborate please. Perhaps providing a specific example because it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the int64edit property **AutoDeclaration** to **Yes** and then you can access the valueStr() when you need it within the scope of "element" (the form).

Otherwise the validate() method should be fine, however, the value won't be correct unless you call it AFTER the super().